# Missing last input in java

Tags: java

With inputs such as; 1 2 3 4, arranged in a column, my code always misses to read the last number. What is wrong?
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    }
   sc.close();
}
```

Comment: can you provide output ? Because it is working on my machine as expected (got all number in row). Add it into you question, it is possible to format it.

Comment: Yeah, I too got everything as expected.

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: Try it with the numbers in a column.

Comment: It's working properly, no miracle at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with 'sc.hasNextInt()' Since there isn't another int after the last entry, the program will not print it. If you change the call from 'hasNextInt()' to 'hasNext()' the code should work (as the final newline character will be read).

You'll note that the following code has a blank space at the end of the input string. You could do something similar and use while sc.hasNext(). On the other hand, you could structure your code differently so that you don't print based on the existence of the next character/int in the input string.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6 ";

  // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
     // check if the scanner's next token is an int
     System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextInt());

     // print what is scanned
     System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
  }

  // close the scanner
  scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: `sc.hasNextInt()` is called _before_ the last input is read, therefore should return true, and in turn print the last value too.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case with the last entry in a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: That post isn't related with this problem at all.